# Editar un formulario con PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

actualmente estoy editando un formulario con 4 campos los cuales son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que utilizo para poder capturar los campos y editarlos

```
<?php
    
    include("conexion.php");
    
    if  (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id=$id";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          $usuario = $row['usuario'];
          $nombre = $row['nombre'];
          $tipo_usuario = $row['tipo_usuario'];
        }
      }
?>
```

Y este es el codigo del formulario

```
 <form action="edit_adm.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">
                                            

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Usuario</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>"  >
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"  class="form-control" >
</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre </label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>"  >
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo de Usuario</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
<select name="tipo_usuario" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $tipo_usuario; ?>"> >              
<option value="1">Administrador</option>
<option value="2">Coordinador de CDA</option>
<option value="3">Supervisor de Zona</option>
<option value="4">Supervisor de Sector</option>
<option value="5">Lider de CDA</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Sin embargo en el campo " Tipo de Usuario " no se como hacer para que me capture el que ya esta segun la base, por ejemplo ese usuario mchavez no es Administrador, y lo muestra asi porque esta en duro en el

los campos Usuario y Nombre si me los captura bien

Agradeceria de su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que tienes que darle la opción de `selected` al `option`

Acá simularé que el elegido es el 4:

```
<?php
$tipo_usuario = 4;
?>

<select name="tipo_usuario" class="form-control">              
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==1){echo "selected";} ?> value="1">Administrador</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==2){echo "selected";} ?> value="2">Coordinador de CDA</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==3){echo "selected";} ?> value="3">Supervisor de Zona</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==4){echo "selected";} ?> value="4">Supervisor de Sector</option>
<option <?php if($tipo_usuario==5){echo "selected";} ?>value="5">Lider de CDA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Verifica el if pues debe ser == y no = pues seria una asignación.

Comment: corregido! amigo, gracias

Comment: Excelente amigo, funciono a la perfeccion

Comment: perfecto! dale +1, Marcala, suscríbete y nos vemos en la prox, adios!

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu campo tipo_usuario en tu base de datos es un integer que según su orden es Administrador u otro ejemplo:

```
1 Administrador
2 Coordinador de CDA
3 Supervisor de Zona
..etc
```

debes entonces rescatar ese numero desde la base y antes de mostrar el select debes asignarle la opción **selected**

```
switch ($tipo_usuario){
case 0 : 
 echo "<option selected value='0'>Administrador</option>";
break; 
case 1 :
 echo "<option selected value='1'>Coordinador</option>";
}

<option value="1">Administrador</option>
<option value="2">Coordinador de CDA</option>
<option value="3">Supervisor de Zona</option>
<option value="4">Supervisor de Sector</option>
<option value="5">Lider de CDA</option>
```

saludos